# How to store array in Redis hashes?

Tags: redis

I'm very new to Redis, and looking to see if its possible to do. Imagine I'm receiving data like this:

```
{ "account": "abc", "name": "Bob", "lname": "Smith" }
{ "account": "abc", "name": "Sam", "lname": "Wilson" }
{ "account": "abc", "name": "Joe"}
```

And receiving this data for another account:

```
{ "account": "xyz", "name": "Bob", "lname": "Smith" } 
{ "account": "xyz", "name": "Sam", "lname": "Smith"}
```

I would like to keep this data in Redis in similar format:

```
abc:name ["Bob", "Sam", "Joe"]
abc:lname ["Smith", "Wilson", Null]
```

And for xyz:

```
xyz:name["Bob", "Sam"]
xyz:lname["Smith", "Smith"]
```

So the question is what data types should I use to store this Redis?

Comment: It depends on how you want to access the data. What's the most important, the account, the name...? I would go for a list containing each hash name.

Comment: I'm guessing for first names and last names are not unique. Do you mean for key "xyz:name" do you want to store set of non-unique values like "Bob" and "Sam"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your goal is to check if `Bob` is used as a `name` for the account `abc` the solution should be something like:

**Sample Data**

```
{ "account": "abc", "name": "Bob", "lname": "Smith" }
{ "account": "abc", "name": "Sam", "lname": "Wilson" }
{ "account": "abc", "name": "Joe"}
```

Do this ([**using a redis set**](http://redis.io/commands#set)):

```
SADD abc:name Bob Sam Joe
SADD abc:lname Wilson Smith
```

You'll then be able to check if `Bob` is used as a `name` for the account `abc`, with:

```
SISMEMBER abc:name Bob
> true
```

To retrieve all values of a field use SMEMBERS:

```
SMEMBERS abc:name
> ["Bob", "Sam", "Joe"]
```

**Note:**

- The key name here is under the `[account]:[field]` format. Where `[account]` can be `abc`, `xyz` and so on and `field` can be `name`, `lname` ...
- If you don't want unique value, for instance:

  `abc:name ["Bob", "Sam", "Joe", "Bob", "Joe"]`

  then you should use [a list](http://redis.io/commands#list) instead[image]

Comment: How can I use the SADD [account]:[field] syntax with node-redis?

Comment: Is account:field a single key? How can I get all key values under account

Comment: Yes "[account]:[field]" is a single key. "How can I get all key values under account" you can't that's not what we want here. "How can I use the SADD [account]:[field] syntax with node-redis" redis.sadd('account:name', 'Bob', (err, ok) => {});