# Store an Array in Redis - RoR 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I have an Item model. There is a way to store all the itens (Item.all) in a Redis database? I have tried this:

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("suggestme", :redis => Redis.new)

$redis.set("itens", Item.all)
```

But when i retrieve the itens:

```
$redis.get("itens")
```

I got a String "#Item::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe399d6e550"

The idea is to store the full array of itens in it

Answer (score 4):

Redis only store string values. If you want to store other kinds of objects, you have to use marshaling. There is a built-in ruby class called [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html), it can help you make it.

```
$redis.set("itens", Marshal.dump(Item.all))
Marshal.load($redis.get("itens"))
```

Comment: @liuzxx could he also use Redis Sets or Hashes with Item.all.to_a? (http://redis.io/topics/data-types). Here is an example of using Set: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19810244/1299792

Comment: No matter which redis data type you use, you can only get the string, not an array.